# Data type errors on haskell regarding arguments

Tags: haskell

So I'm new to haskell and I'm not quite sure how to do certain things
Not many online tutorials even address the problem I'm having, so I figured I'd ask here finally

This is my code: (It's in an lhs file)

```
> data PointVal = PointVal Float Float Float Float
>                 deriving (Show)


> parabolaCordDistance :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float
> parabolaCordDistance x1 x2 y1 y2
>       abc = PointVal x1 x2 y1 y2     
>
>
```

So now the error I'm getting regarding this is :

```
Extension.lhs:17:3:
    Couldn't match expected type `t0 -> PointVal'
                with actual type `Float'
    The equation(s) for `parabolaCordDistance' have five arguments,
    but its type `Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float'
    has only four
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I'm basically trying to create a data type called PointVal where the 4 floats act as x and y co-ordinates.
Then I'm trying to input these using ParabolaCordDistance 
And using abc as a variable in the data type "PointVal"

If anyone could help remove this error; or point out where I've gone wrong and how to fix it, that'd be great!

Comment: there's no need to paste LHS if all you're pasting is code and no comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this syntax:

```
> parabolaCordDistance x1 x2 y1 y2 = 3 where
>       abc = PointVal x1 x2 y1 y2
```

This defines a variable `abc`, local to `parabolaCordDistance`, with value `PointVal x1 x2 y1 y2`. You will of course want to change the return value `3` to some more meaningful computation; that's just for the sake of making a complete example.

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I think I've misinterpreted your specific issue; Daniel has nailed it though! I'm keeping my answer though as it might still be useful and is definitely moderately relevant.

---

A type signature of the form `a -> b -> c -> d -> e` indicates a function with **FOUR** arguments (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) not five — the last item is the type of the return value (`e`).

So when you are defining the body of such function, you should only define it with the right number of arguments, and the return value is not an argument.

In your case, the signature is `Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Float` which "translates" to "a function that takes 4 floats and returns a float".

---

So first remove the 5th `abc` argument from the implementation definition

```hs
parabolaCordDistance x1 x2 y1 y2 = PointVal x1 x2 y1 y2
```

and secondly I think `PointVal` is what you are returning not a `Float` so you need to adapt your type signature to

```hs
parabolaCordDistance :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> PointVal
```

---

you can also just remove the type annotation and ask on a GHCi prompt what Haskell thinks the type of the function is (after removing the extraneous/bogus `abc` arg, which you didn't really mean):

```hs
*> :t parabolaCordDistance
parabolaCordDistance :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> PointVal
```

---

But note that the definition of `parabolaCordDistance`, considering its current implementation, can be simplified to

```hs
parabolaCordDistance = PointVal
```

but I'm assuming you possibly wanted to add more processing to the function at a later phase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, especially with `abc`. Your code is interpreted as

```
parabolaCordDistance x1 x2 y1 y2 abc = PointVal x1 x2 y1 y2
```

so the function `parabolaCordDistance` is getting five arguments. This is not in agreement with the type, which says it takes four `Float` arguments. That's the error you're getting.

Comment: Oh right
So bascially What I'm aiming to do (I really really really suck at haskell ) is trying to use the values x1 x2 y1 y2 as the input for the variable abc

by that I mean the 4 posssible float values in the PointVal for abc should be x1 x2 y1 y2

Comment: @theSun: It seems there are many things a bit mixed up in your understanding of the code. Once you declare `data PointVal` the structure of the type is fixed so you cannot "add" variables. You can use `abc` as a local variable (inside `parabolaCordDistance`), in that case you need to add `where`/`let` appropriately. But that only makes sense if you're going to then do something with `abc`. If you're trying to construct a value, there's no need to define a function for that. `PointVal` can be used directly. How are you learning Haskell?

Comment: Using this book (http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html) 

But I see where I went wrong now, and I've understood what you mean
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should better use more explicit way to create 2d point

```
data Point = Point (Float, Float) (Float, Float)
             deriving (Show)
```

result in ghci

```
*Main> Point (1,1) (2,2)
Point (1.0,1.0) (2.0,2.0)
```